# NullReference error when adding a new model into a model property

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following entity framework code first models:

```
public class Member {

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public String CardNumber { get; set; }

    //Foreign Key
    public virtual ICollection<Favorite> Favorites { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<SelectListItem> FavoriteTypes { get; set; }

    public Member() {
        MembersDB db = new MembersDB();

        FavoriteTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
        FavoriteTypes.AddRange(db.FavoriteTypes.ToList().Select(f => new SelectListItem { Text = f.Value, Value = f.ID.ToString() }));
    }
}

public class FavoriteType {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Favorite {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }

    //Foreign Keys
    public virtual FavoriteType FavoriteType { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

This creates a 1-M relationship for FavoriteTypes -> Favorites and 1-M relations for Member -> Favorites

Within my controller action, I retrieve most of the Member's info from Session saved at a couple pages back except for the favorites info which is gathered below. Then I gather the list of ID and input values to add to my new member as so:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddFavs(List<int> ID, List<string> Value) {
        MembersDB db = new MembersDB();
        Member newMember = (Member)Session["member"];
        if (ID != null && Value != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ID.Count(); i++)
            {
                int currentID = ID[i];
                var test = new Favorite();
                test.FavoriteType = db.FavoriteTypes.Where(f => f.ID == currentID).FirstOrDefault();
                test.Value = Value[i];
                newMember.Favorites.Add(test);                    
            }
        }
```

While running this code I get a NullReference error on this line `newMember.Favorites.Add(test);`

Not entirely sure why, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: while troubleshooting in VS, the only null properties I can find are `Favorites` in `newMember` and `Member` in `test`

Comment: Your class is called `Member` yet your constructor is called `SceneMember`. Which one is right?

Comment: That was a typo it's Member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ICollection<Favorite> Favorites` is `null`, so you can't add items to it. You should instantiate it in the constructor of your model:

```
public Member()
{
    Favorites = new List<Favorite>();

    // ...
}
```

Now it's an empty collection and you can add items to it.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it was something this simple.

Comment: @GregB no problem, glad I could help. I think it's a common mistake when designing models.